# How to read particular set of bits from two or more bytes in C language

Tags: c, arrays, byte, bit

How to read particular set of bits from two or more bytes so that it can be put under one array.
For example:

```
0100 0011    0110 1100
```

Here it is 2 byte .I wanted bits index starting in first byte till the bit which is in second byte and store it in an array.

Comment: Look up bitwise shifts `<<` and `>>`, and bitwise OR `|` operators.

Comment: You mean get an array which will contains {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0} (in this example)?

Comment: No.I want set of bits which starts from one byte(say index 3) and ends in another byte(say index 11) by taking two bytes together.

Comment: could you post some graphic that indicates 'index 3' and 'index 11' and how you want the final result to look?   Please post the code showing what you have tried and how that differs from what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Operator **>>** will shift each bit in the byte to the right

The approach here is to shift the desired bit to the right-most position. So, for the first bit we must shift by 7 positions to the right, for the second bit we shift by 6, and so on.

The operator **&** performs a bit-to-bit AND. So, performing like this:

```
0x01 & (some_value)
```

will consider only the right-most bit (LSB) of the byte.

The rest of the code is just logic to put the bits in the right place in the array

```
   int  i   = 0;
   char bt1 = 0x43;
   char bt2 = 0x6c;

   char bit_array[16];

   // Get bits from bt1
   for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
   {
      bit_array[i] = 0x01 & ( bt1 >> (7-i) );
   }

   // Get bits from bt2
   for (i = 8; i < 16; i++ )
   {
      bit_array[i] = 0x01 & ( bt2 >> (15-i) );
   }

   printf("bit_array is: \n");

   for (i = 0; i < sizeof(bit_array); i++ )
   {
      printf("%d ", bit_array[i]);
   }

   printf("\n");

   // Shoud print
   //bit_array is:
   //0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: I want set of bits which starts from one byte(say index 3) and ends in another byte(say index 11) by taking two bytes together(not using two for loop).